# page 404 served with 200 response status nginx gnunicorn django

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I'm setting up error pages on a django site in dev I get the error with the good status code but on production the HTTP responses code does not match, I'm receiving 200 response on 404. I assume that nginx is rendering Django 404 as 200 but I don't how to properly define the 404 error response on nginx side

Django:

```
    #views :
    from django.shortcuts import render

    def handler404(request):
        return render(request,'public/404.html', status=404)

    #urls.py:
    ...
    handler404 = 'public.views.404.handler404'
```

Nginx:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.myproject.fr;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }

    }
```

Edit : Proxy_params :

```
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: In dev you don't have the same setup as in production?

Comment: in dev I use the django runserver, in prod I use nginx and gunicorn

Comment: Should I need something like add_header to pass the http code from django to nginx ?